# Cocoapods installation error - curl: (56) Recv failure: Connection reset by peer

Tags: ios, curl, google-analytics, cocoapods

I am installing cocoapods by using terminal and getting below error **only when** working with Google Analytics and google sign (`#pod 'Google/Analytics' pod 'Google/SignIn'`)

My Podfile:-

```
platform :ios, '7.0'

target 'ProgrammingCrew' do

pod 'AFNetworking', '~> 2.5.3'
pod 'TPKeyboardAvoiding'
pod 'TTTAttributedLabel'
pod 'MBProgressHUD'
pod 'TSMessages'
pod 'FBSDKLoginKit'
pod 'NewRelicAgent'
pod 'CocoaLumberjack'
pod 'Google/Analytics'
pod 'Google/SignIn'
pod 'RNBlurModalView', '~> 0.1.0'

end
```

Error:-
[image]

**NOTE**:-
When I remove Google sign in and Google analytics from pod file, it works well.

```
OS 10.10.5
XCode 7.2
```

Comment: This issue occur when you have poor internet connectivity. try with better internet connectivity

Comment: Right said, the poor internet connectivity can be a reason for this.

Answer (score 0):

This error is thrown when there is a network failure. It can be either at your end, or at the place where that particular source code is kept. I was facing the same problem and it worked after few hours. Had to make no changes for that at all.

It can also be the case that the link is no more working at all in which case we have to get a working link(Pod with some other version). If no such links exist, we might have to notify the developer/(s) about this.

Comment: Thanks for sharing you valuable inputs.